# Specifying cell selection range in didSelectRowAt of UITableView In Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a `UIImageView` in the `TableViewCell`.

The `UIImageView` will function as a checkbox.

I want to execute `didSelectRowAt` when I click the part of the cell except the `UIImageView`.

Currently, `didSelectRowAt` is executed even when clicking anywhere.

Plz answer how to cancel the execution of `didSelectRowAt` by clicking on the `UIImageView` part of the cell.

Comment: You either need to use a `UIButton` instead of a `UIImageView` or you will need to add your own `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UIImageView`.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok! I will try it with Button instead of `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIButton instead of UIImageView to checkbox functionality. Set check and uncheck images on the button for selected and normal state. Using the button, your problem will get resolved.

If you want to use imageView, then just enable user interaction of that imageView in the cell. It will work fine.

Comment: I think once again, there was no reason to use Image instead of Button. Thank you!